# AFNetworking pod install use of unresolved identifier methods

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, afnetworking

I install `Mixpanel` to my project and `AFNetworking` doesn't work anymore and in all methods show me this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager'

But Xcode have link to the class in the method, I tried `pod install`, `pod update`, clean the project and it doesn't work

In PodFile:

```
target 'My Project' do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Mixpanel'
end

target 'Mi ProjectTests' do
end
```

In Bridging-Header:

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import <Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h>
```

[image]

and the last error show is:

```
ld: framework not found -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
```

Comment: Eduardo, please try to post your implementation. Then it'll be more clear what your issue comes from.

Comment: @pedrouan look now

Comment: OK, it looks that AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is no longer supported. What version of AFNetworking has been installed with that pod?

Comment: the last AFNetworking (3.1.0)

Comment: OK, please what is your XCode version and Swift version?

Comment: Xcode Version 7.3.1 and swift suppose 2.2 i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121865/discussion-between-eduardo-oliveros-and-pedrouan).

Answer (score 3):

To AFNetworking 3.0 version:

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
```

To solve the last error go to `Build Settings`, `Other Linker Flags` and remove all except `$(inherited)`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after I update pod to the latest version of AFNetworking. There wasn't a AFHTTPRequestOperationManager anymore, so try to call this:

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
```

Upload task with progress, in **swift 3.0** like this:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com/your/url")!)
manager.uploadTask(with: request, from: userData, progress: { (progress: Progress) in

       // progress catching

    }) { (response: URLResponse, object: Any?, error: Error?) in

       // work with response 
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to change the version of this pod, because change this in all classes is longest, if i pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0' the error that appear is ld: framework not found AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Does your IDE give you any suggestions when start to type 'let manager =  AFNet...', what are they, if they appear?

Comment: in the migration how do you do uploadProgressForTask ?

Comment: what kind of migration? And what's an answer to my prev question, please

Comment: migration from 2.0 to 3.0 in afnetworking and yes, they appear but i decide migrate to the last pod

Comment: Updated my answer. Try to type those function methods, you should see right syntax for your swift version.

Comment: the solution doesn't work error is ld: framework not found -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121862/discussion-between-pedrouan-and-eduardo-oliveros).